# VueJS: one component for many routes

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I'm a newbie to the world of VueJS.

My app uses `vue-router` to handle with routes changing. This's how it's configured:

```
new Router({
  routes: [{
    path: "/",
    component: Articles
  }, {
    path: "/articles/:category",
    component: Articles
  }]
});
```

As you can see, I've got 2 routes handled by the same component. The idea is very simple. When we're on a home page, show articles from any category. When we're on a category page, show articles from that category.

The question is, how a component can detect whether the route's changed, e.g, from home page to category page?

I've come with this solution:

```
function loadArticles() {};

Vue.component("Articles", {
  mounted: loadArticles,
  watch: { "$route": loadArticles }
});
```

But I think, that's a bad solution.

Comment: Why would watching the $route object be a bad idea ? It's recommended way in Vue Router Docs, when you want to fetch data after route is activated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I have done on a little project of mine, I'm using the template to display single article

This is my router

```
   '/post/:id': {
    name: 'post',
    component: require('./components/article.vue')
},
```

In my `.vue` file, I get the `$route.params` to get the `id` of the article then displayed it in my `ready` function.

```
  $.get('api/posts/' + this.$route.params.id, function(data){
            myPost.current = data;
        })
```

You'll need to get the `category` parameter then rendered the template according to it.

Answer (score 1):

It should look something like this:

```
watch: {
    '$route' (to, from) {
        if (this.$route.params.category) {
            this.loadArticles(category);
        } else {
            this.loadArticles();
        }
    }
}
```

'watch' is recommended [here, in docs](http://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html).